# Dropdown selected value from database to be bind in complete list from another table asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a Master table in database with `BANK_ID` & `BANK_DESC` columns. I have a transaction table with `BANK_ID`, where after submitting form, `BANK_ID` gets submitted. I want to fetch the list from Master table where selected value from transaction table should be selected.
I have two different pages: 
1. a dropdownlist whose values gets stored in database.
2. i want to fetch that dropdown value as selected value by default into the dropdown list shown in first page.

My aspx page markup:

```
<table>  
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBankName" runat="server" 
                 AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Width="75%" 
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My C# code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            getBank();
        }

        string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Master LEFT JOIN BANK ON Master.BANK_ID = Transaction.BANK_ID";
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ddlBankName.Items.FindByValue(dr["BANK_DESC"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
}

public void getBank()
{
    ddlBankName.Items.Clear();

    ddlBankName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
    clsDataAccess cls = new clsDataAccess();

    string sql = "SELECT BANK_ID,BANK_DESC FROM Master";

    DataTable dt = cls.GetDataTable(sql);

    ddlBankName.DataTextField = "BANK_DESC";
    ddlBankName.DataValueField = "BANK_ID";

    ddlBankName.DataSource = dt;
    ddlBankName.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged. Also what is your actual problem?

Comment: There is no code in ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: The actual problem is BANK_DESC does not appear as selected from database in dropdown list. It should come as dropdownlist with selected value as default from databse.

Comment: Put the SQL into the ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged. Otherwise selecting a value from the list will do nothing.

Comment: Actually, i have created two aspx pages. In one, i am submitting the values into database. In 2nd, i am trying to fetch it from databse

Comment: While fetching, dropdown list should be populated and the default value should be the submitted value from 1st aspx page.